# JSON Schema Validation validate array items not working

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Here is the thing I'm trying to validate:

**[REMOVED AFTER EDIT - PLEASE SEE EDIT BELOW FOR UP TO DATE CODE]**

This should fail because only the item that should be acceptable here is "merchants" - but the validation doesn't fail. It passes.

I've can't work this out. I've tried a few approaches and it's got me nowhere.

What is wrong here?

**---------------------- EDIT ----------------------------**

I've been asked to provide more code. Here is the payload I need to validate. It's in **PHP**.

```
$payload = (object) [];
$payload->query_string = (object) [];
$payload->query_string->include = (object) [
    "merchant_channel",
    "merchant",
];
```

Here is the line that will run the validator:

```
$this->validator->validate(
    $payload,
    ['$ref' => 'file://Schemas/the-json-file.json']
);
```

And here is the file that I'm running the validator against:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "query_string": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "include": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "values": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                      "language"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using this package:

https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

This package is quite simply....

> A PHP Implementation for validating JSON Structures against a given Schema.

You shouldn't have to know PHP to able to answer my **original** question which is specific to JSON Schema Validation!

Please don't comment/answer saying something like "You've missed a quote" or "You've missed a closing bracket". Obviously I've **had** to cut this code down so I can post it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you need a Js or Java solution?

Comment: Standard or with Node.js?

Comment: Standard. I’m using PHP as the backend with the Justin Rainbow Json Schema lib

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the instance you're trying to validate in JSON please? I don't know that debug notation.

Comment: @Relequestual I don't know what that means but I've dramatically altered the text in my question to include a lot more information.

Comment: OK. The problem for me was I didn't know the PHP notation you're using.

Comment: I see a problem with your input... The schema says you should have query_string->include->values, where `values` is an array, and the items in the array must be a string of "language". (you can remove the allOf in your example.

Comment: JSON Schema is for validating a JSON instance against the schema. Try writing your JSON that you're trying to validate in JSON for this example. Should hopefully make things clearer and you can check your expectations are correct by using something like https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ (I'll check back here on the monday)

Answer (score 0):

It lacks starting and ending curly braces.

Comment: It's reduced for brevity in my question.